# Payment Integration using Just Card Number Visa/MasterCard etc | No Stripe, No Paypal, No PayTm, No RazorPay etc

Tags: django, payment-gateway, payment, mastercard

I am developing a web app that supports Online payment in Django.
Stripe, Paypal, RazorPay, etc does not support my country.

I would like to have those type of payment integration which Google and some other companies uses.

Like: Payment through just Card Number + Expiry date and 3-digit pin(from the back of card)

Is there any library or method available to do this task using Django

Thanks in advance

Comment: As in, you're looking for a provider that caters to your country? Or you want to become a payment provider yourself?

Comment: To become myself as payment provider not a bad idea, But at this time, I want to use it for my e-commerce website

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. You can use a payment provider that works in your country, or you can become a payment provider.

Becoming a payment provider is a very long and expensive journey, and extremely complex.

You will need to find a payment provider that works for your country and then integrate with them using their API.